# Can not run TestDistributedShell in eclipse

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I could run TestDistributedShell in maven successfully, but failed in eclipse. Is there any extra setting I need to do ?

Here's the error messages I got in eclipse:

```
2014-01-22 14:19:49,198 WARN  [AsyncDispatcher event handler] resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger (RMAuditLogger.java:logFailure(255)) - USER=zhangj82    OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED   PERMISSIONS=Application application_1390371576457_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1390371576457_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127 due to: Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same exception while trying to install hadoop on my mac and I solved the problem by explicitly defining java home at yarn-env.sh and hadoop-env.sh files

so go to etc/hadoop and edit hadoop-env.sh and yarn-env.sh files with explicit java home directory.

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...

good luck!